# React Native app doesn't load on IOS versions 11 and 12

Tags: ios, iphone, react-native, browserstack

When a user opens the app (from a physical device or a simulator) it just shows a blank screen and close (looks like a 0.5s flash, really fast).

Testing it on browserstack simulator (https://www.browserstack.com/) it works on IOS versions greater or equal to 13, but not in 11 or 12.

- The iOS deployment target of the project is set to 11. All our dependencies also have their iOS deployment targets set to 11 or below;
- React Native version: 0.64.1

While debugging it (in browserstack) some errors looks common on all failure devices (all those in IOS version 11 or 12), for example (this is the most common and maybe even the root of the troubles):

```
<Error>: _WifyCopyUnserialized: Invalid buffer/buffersize
```

- Here you can see what happens when we try to open our app (showing half screen to keep the app name hidden):

[image]

- Complete log looks like the following in all failing versions:

[image: Our logs from browserstack]

Someone there already faced something like it or similar?
Any suggestion about actions to be done in this case (app not opening in specific IOS versions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was with a problematic version of a package called `react-native-share`. More details about this: https://giters.com/react-native-share/react-native-share/issues/1095.

Updating this package solved it :)